# What is the suitable setting for supercoherence with value in a bicategory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, coherence

It was J.F. Jardine established the so called supercoherence theory in [Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra Volume 75, Issue 2, 18 October 1991, Pages 103–194](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499190122I). The result can be roughly stated as follows:

---

A pseudo-functor $\Delta^{op}\to \mathbf{Cat}$, from the opposite of simplex category  to the 2-category of small categories, is fully determined by its value on objects, face maps and degeneracy maps, natural isomorphisms corresponding to the standard simplicial identities, and a small list of higher order coherence conditions (consisting 17 identities).

---

This supercoherence subsumes "all diagrams commute type" coherence for monoidal category, bicategory(?).

Now it's natural to replace the target strict 2-category $\mathbf{Cat}$ by a general bicategory $\mathbf{C}$. Is the naive analogue still true?

The naive approach is first looking at any strict 2-cateogry, then embedding a bicategory in a strict 2-category by the coherence theorem for bicategory. I do not know if this works actually.

Comment: The coherence theorem for bicategories states that every bicategory is equivalent to a strict one. What do you mean by embedding into a strict 2-cat?

Comment: @StephanMüller I am saying the same thing. One way to show the coherence theorem is to consider the Yoneda functor, which is an embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the strictness is not very relevant here since the commutative diagrams are of certain 2-morphisms which are given as data. I don't think that in any place there you need to consider triple compositions of 1-morphisms, so the comparisons simply don't appear.